# Printing custom HTML page with its css

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a web page contain 8 small tables, the page will not appear for the user, I will fill it dynamically from database when the user click on print button, I designed the page and all is good, but when I click on print button I lost all css design, and the every table will be in a row.

- I tried to add `media="all"` in `<link>` attributes but didn't work.

[Desired printed page should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBRJV.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all"/>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="container-fluid">

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>

        <script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
        </script>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody> <tr> <td> Branch </td> <td> AS </td> </tr> <tr> <td> Loan Type </td> <td>SA</td> </tr></tbody> 
                </table>
            </div>
       </div>

        <p>Informations</p>

       <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                            <td> ID # </td> 
                            <td>SA</td> 
                        </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td> Name </td>
                                <td>SA </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Gender </td>
                                <td>SA</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Birth Date </td>
                                <td>SA </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Mother </td>
                                <td>SA</td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td> Address </td>
                                <td>SA </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Tel # </td>
                                <td>SA</td>
                            </tr>  
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
           <div class="col-sm-1"> </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4">
               <table class="table table-bordered">
                   <tbody>
                       <tr>
                           <td> Job </td>
                           <td>SA </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td> Funder Type </td>
                           <td>SA</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td> Martial Status </td>
                           <td>SA </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td> Place Of Birth </td>
                           <td>SA</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td> J </td>
                           <td>SA </td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
           </div>
        </div> 

        <p> Financial Information </p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Active Date </td>
                            <td>SA</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Total Amount </td>
                            <td>SA </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> To Pay </td>
                            <td>SA</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Bussniess </td>
                            <td>SA </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Mother </td>
                            <td>SA</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Job </td>
                            <td>SA </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Funder Type </td>
                            <td>SA</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Martial Status </td>
                            <td>SA </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Place Of Birth </td>
                            <td>SA</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Job </td>
                            <td>SA </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Funder Type </td>
                            <td>SA</td>
                        </tr>
                       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <p> Financial Information </p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7" class="text-center"> Garantees </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Sign </td>
                            <td>Name </td>
                            <td> Amount </td>
                            <td> Currency </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Sign </td>
                            <td>Name </td>
                            <td> Amount </td>
                            <td> Currency </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7" class="text-center"> Garantores </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Sign </td>
                            <td>Name </td>
                            <td> Amount </td>
                            <td> Currency </td>
                            <td>Name </td>
                            <td> Amount </td>
                            <td> Currency </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Sign </td>
                            <td>Name </td>
                            <td> Amount </td>
                            <td> Currency </td>
                            <td>Name </td>
                            <td> Amount </td>
                            <td> Currency </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div> 


    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for printing, the media is print , why all ? Can you clarify the question with a short examplz showing your issue ?

Comment: i tried media print and also didn't work, wait

Comment: I edited the question to add the code @G-Cyr

Comment: Seems to work to me. It doesn't fit on a single page , maybe decreasing the font size. But tables do stand side by side when enough room. here is what i get  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZL34.jpg

Comment: it works when I show it in full screen, but didn't work in normal screen

Comment: Sorry, the screen i just shared was about print preview on A4 paper and portrait mode. It is a little different from screen , but thats normal, it is a different media too ;) You may want to set your print on landscape ?